# PHPExcel edit cells and resave - 'Invalid Cell Coordinate'

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to modify a downloaded googe doc spreadsheet and then save it to my server.
The download of the file is fine, I get it saved to my server and it opens ok and everything is fine. The issue arises when I load the file into PHPExcel object and then modify some of the cells and then resave the modified file.
Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Ignore the lines getting the stock value from database, they are coded correctly in my code I've just removed the query from the pasted code sample.

I get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate 'CURRENT PRODUCTS'!A2' in .. /PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:508 Stack trace: #0 ....

```
function updateDoc($url)
{
    file_put_contents("filename.xlsx",fopen($url,"r"));
    $filename = "filename.xlsx";
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $excel2 = $objReader->load('filename.xlsx'); 
    $excel2->setActiveSheetIndexByName("Current Products");
    $rowIterator = $excel2->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
    $rows = 1;
    $columnAsLetters = 'E';
    foreach($rowIterator as $row)
    {
        if($rows <= 2)
        {   
            continue;//skip first 2 rows
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $excel2->getActiveSheet()->getCell($columnAsLetters.$rows)->getCalculatedValue();
            $sku = trim($data);
            $stock = //** I select stock from database **// 
            $r = //** returned sql row **//
            $stk = $r[0];
            $excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("G" . $rows, $stk);
        }
        $rows++;
    }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(FALSE);
    $objWriter->save('filename2.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: What's the line in your code that throws the exception and what's the actual value you're trying to save?

Comment: @Alon As far as I can tell by commenting out various sections its the last line $objWriter->save('filename2.xlsx'); that throws the error. I'm just trying to overwrite a stock value in Column G with a new stock value taken from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally got this working. I've had to rewrite it so that I create a second PHPExcel object and create a new file by copying each cell value from the original file into the new file and updating the values I want to update as I copy the file across to the new one. 
I've manually set the number of columns/rows to copy because I have an idea of how many is required. I also had to modify the Calculation.php file of PHPExcel as there is a vlookup in my file that references a sheet that doesn't exist in the file and it kept throwing an error of calling cellExists function on a non object so I added a check to see if the sheet exists before trying to get the cell. My code is now:

```
function updateDoc($url)
{
    file_put_contents("filename.xlsx",fopen($url,"r"));
    $filename = "filename.xlsx";
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    $objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $sheets = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($filename);
    // Created file 
    $objPHPExcel2 = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel2->getProperties()->setCreator("User")
                    ->setLastModifiedBy("User")
                    ->setTitle("filename2")
                    ->setSubject("filename2")
                    ->setDescription("filename2")
                    ->setCategory("PublicWEB");
    $s=0;
    foreach($sheets as $sheet)
    {
        if($s != 0)
        {
            $objPHPExcel2->createSheet($s);
            $objPHPExcel2->getSheet($s)->setTitle($sheet);
        }
        else
        {
            $objPHPExcel2->getSheet($s)->setTitle($sheet);
        }
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheet);
        $objPHPExcel2->setActiveSheetIndex($s);
        for($rows = 1 ; $rows < 250 ; $rows++)
        {
            for ($col=0 ;$col < 100 ; $col++) 
            {

                $cellV = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $rows)->getValue();
                if($sheet == "Current Products" && $col == 6 && $rows > 2)
                {
                    $data = $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$rows)->getValue();
                    $sku = trim($data);
                    if($sku != "")
                    {
                        $stock = $mysqli->query("SELECT stock FROM table WHERE partno = '$sku'");
                        if($stock->num_rows > 0)
                        {
                            $r = $stock->fetch_array();
                            $stk = $r[0];
                            $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rows, $stk );

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rows, "NA" );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rows, "" );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $rows, $cellV );

                }
            }
        }
        ++$s;
    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel2, 'Excel2007'); 
    $objWriter->save('filename2.xlsx');
}
```